# How to copy data from columns I to M to the next worksheet, and then the data from columns P to T immediately follows?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007, copy-paste

I'm a new user so I can't post a picture of the worksheet. Sorry for that.

I hope you understand the worksheet I'm describing baswd on these.

Here's how the sheet looks like. 
I have to copy the values in columns I to M into the next sheet named Consolidated. The values from columns P to T should follow immediately.

It should also take note that the data to be copied has corresponding values in columns D to F.

Thank you for taking time to read this.

Answer (score 1):

This will copy columns I to M in `Sheet1` and paste them to `Consolidated` so that columns P to T come immediately after the copied columns

```
Sub CopyColumns()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("I:M").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Consolidated").Columns("K:O")
End Sub
```

Is that what was required?